# Convergence of a Sequence of Functions

Tags: general-topology, functions, continuity

The context: verifying the group axioms for the fundamental group, specifically that every element has a unique inverse. Below is a non-example, and I am tasked with explaining $why$ it fails.

Let $\alpha : [0,1]\rightarrow X$ be a continuous loop based at $p \in X$. Define $f_s(t) : [0,1]\times[0,1]\rightarrow X$ by
$$f_s(t) = \left\{ \begin{array}{ll} \alpha\left(\frac{2t}{1 - s}\right) &: 0 \le t \le \frac{1 - s}{2} \\ p &: \frac{1 - s}{2} < t < \frac{1 + s}{2}\\ \alpha^{-1}\left(\frac{2t}{1 + s} - 1\right)&: \frac{1 + s}{2} \le t \le 1 \end{array} \right.$$

My explanation of why this map is $not$ a homotopy is that it is not continuous ($\alpha$ is traversed at infinite speed).

My question is: is $\lim_{s\rightarrow 1} f_s(t)$ the constant function $p$? Or does it not exist? I ask because my plan was to use the $(\epsilon, \delta)$-definition to show that the function is not continuous at $s = 1$, but I am not too familiar with sequences of functions.

Comment: The map fails because $f_1(0)$ is not defined